# Laravel HTML form on multiple pages

Tags: forms, laravel

How to make a form across multiple pages in Laravel like here

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-order-form.html

I have a lot of input fields and i can't find any info on Laravel multiple pages forms. If someone has any good website where to read about it and to see how it is done?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you create "tabs" instead of multiple pages / views. If you really want multiple pages you will have to store everything in the users session. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve through `session` of laravel, you can set your values with `key` and `value`:

```
public function step1(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->put('key', 'value');
}
```

for further information see  [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session)

Other way is make in your client side, with `localStorage` is cleaner for me, you can use Single Page Aplication and send the data when you're at the final step.

localStorage works seemed to PHP session, check out  [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) :

you can set the item thought steps, like this:

```
 localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

and retrieve the information like this:

```
 localStorage.getItem("key");
```

The Single Page application lets you render diferent pages in a route and it's not neccesary to reload the page, you can check out Angular or Ember.js Framework.

Comment: Can you give some more info for this second way with LocalStorage, maybe a link or something?

Comment: @lewis4u actually if you use `localStorage`, the single page application (SPA) is optional as you can store your data through the navigation, and if you're gonna use SPA, you can omit to use `localStorage`

Comment: Oh i just think there is a better way and simpler with compact() can someone confirm this??? to save the data from first request and just to route user to next form with compact()

Comment: @lewis4u Yes, you could pass the data incoming from the request and set to the next view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112927/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-jose-rojas).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this on server side and not with javascript framework here is what you can approach.

You can make use of Laravel session to store intermediate data between the pages and then pull data out of session to insert into database at the final step.

Detailed Tutorial
https://www.5balloons.info/multi-page-step-form-in-laravel-with-validation/